# Add image size depending on number of posts with counter in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com) and have built the following repeater:

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    if( have_rows('image_builder') ):
    while ( have_rows('image_builder') ) : the_row();
    $count++;
?>
    <?php
        if ($count == 1) {
            $image_size = 'there-is-1-image';
        }

        if ($count == 2) {
            $image_size = 'there-are-2-images';
        }

        if ($count == 3) {
            $image_size = 'there-are-3-images';
        }

        if ($count == 4) {
            $image_size = 'there-are-4-images';
        }
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_sub_field('image'), $image_size );
    ?>
<?php
    endwhile;
    else:
    echo '<p>Please add some images.</p>';
    endif;
?>
```

The repeater simply allows admin to add up to 4 images. Depending on the number of images, I'd like a certain image size to be applied.

For example, if 3 images have been added, I'd like the `$image-size` "there-are-3-images" to be applied to each image.

As you can see, I've added my counter, but I don't think I'm using the correct operator.

The result is:

`<img src="/img-1.jpg" class="size-there-is-1-image">`

`<img src="/img-2.jpg" class="size-there-are-2-images">`

`<img src="/img-3.jpg" class="size-there-are-3-images">`

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need one foreach to count the images or get the image count via a function.

The problem you've is that you can't know how many pictures are following in your `$count` and you output in every loop.

But what is defined in `$image-size` can`t you achieve what you want with css like nth-child or flexbox?

In your case a possible soulution is:

```
<?php

    if( have_rows('image_builder') ):
        $count = 0;
    while ( have_rows('image_builder') ) : the_row();
        $count++;
    endwhile;


    switch ($count) {
        case 0:
            $image_size = 'there-is-1-image';
        break;
        case 1:
            $image_size = 'there-are-2-images';
        break;
        case 2:
            $image_size = 'there-are-3-images';
        break;
        case 2:
            $image_size = 'there-are-4-images';
        break;
    }
    while ( have_rows('image_builder') ) : the_row();
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_sub_field('image'), $image_size );
    endwhile;

    else:
    echo '<p>Please add some images.</p>';
    endif;
```

(The code ist not tested)

Comment: I can achieve this with css, but `wp_get_attachment_image` is using img src set, so I'd like the correct image size to be used depending on the images added. Can you show an example of the foreach or link me to an example?

Comment: i added an example